# Ruby on Rails: undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, haml

I have a Photo Share web app and I am trying to add comments in photos. I can't spot any mistakes. Maybe in the controller class in index function is the problem. There is an undefined method error when I try to show-post comments below the photo. Error in HAML code.

```
Error: - if @photo_comments.any?
```

Controller:

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @photo_comments = Comment.where(photo_id: => photo_id)
  end

  def create
    @comment = Comment.create(user_id: params[:user_id], photo_id: params[:photo_id], text: params[:comment][:text])
    flash[:notice] = "Successfully added a comment"
    redirect_to :back
  end

  private
    def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:user_id, :photo_id, :text)
    end

end
```

Model:

```
class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :photo
end
```

Database:

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.integer :user_id
      t.integer :photo_id
      t.string :text
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

View:

```
%p Comments
- if @photo_comments.any?
  - @photo_comments.each do |comment|
    .bold-text= "#{comment.user.email}: "
    .normal-text= comment.text
    %br
- else
  .text No comments for this photo yet! 
%br
%br
%p
  = form_for Comment.new(), :url => user_photo_comments_path do |form|
    = form.label :text, 'Add a Comment'
    %br
    = form.text_area :text
    %br
    = form.submit 'Post'
```

Routes:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  get '/' => 'home#index'
  resources :users do
    resources :photos do
      resources :comments
    end
    resources :follows
  end

  resources :tags, only: [:create, :destroy]
  get '/log-in' => "sessions#new"
  post '/log-in' => "sessions#create"
  get '/log-out' => "sessions#destroy", as: :log_out

end
```

Comment: What URL do you call when you get that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line seems a bit problematic:

```rb
@photo_comments = Comment.where(photo_id: => photo_id)
```

I can spot a couple of potential errors here:

- hash syntax: you are mixing both styles, you should use `photo_id: photo_id` or (Ruby pre 1.9) `:photo_id => photo_id`
- the method or variable `photo_id` seems not defined in that controller, maybe you would mean `params[:photo_id]`?

Comment: Still the same error.

Comment: Probably due to other reasons... but these 2 points should be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

There is definitely a syntax error on this line:

```
@photo_comments = Comment.where(photo_id: => photo_id)
```

also `photo_id` is not defined anywhere in the controller so maybe it should instead look like:

```
@photo_comments = Comment.where(photo_id: params[:photo_id])
```

?

The error `undefined_method` often comes when calling a method on a `nil` value. In your case instance variable `@photo_comments` is nil thus giving you undefined_method error in views.

Answer (score 0):

These two line make no sense:

```
- if @photo_comments.nil?
  - @photo_comments.each do |comment|
```

If the instance variable `@photo_comments` is `nil` then iterate of it? Of course, you will get an `undefined method 'each' for nil:NilClass` in that case.

I guess you mean something like this:

```
- unless @photo_comments.nil?
  - @photo_comments.each do |comment|
```

Comment: Edited to "any"

Comment: `any?` will fail too if `@photo_comments` is `nil`. `any?` only works for enumerables.

Comment: OP might be looking for `.present?`